# How to solve SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 in magento 2 multistore checkout page

Tags: magento, magento2

Hi i got this error while submit order in magento 2 multistore view: 
Order saving error: ``` SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name '', query was: INSERT INTO `` () VALUES () ```

[image: Check this image]

Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Thank You edit this post @daniel

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Would you please tell me that you have migrated from Magento1.9 to Magento 2? If yes Then I have a solution for you

Comment: @Manish I'm facing the same issue and YES I've migrated from Magento 1.14.3.6 to 2.1.13